# Scoping issue in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a simple program to try to understand the scoping rules in Haskell:

```
myfunc =
let x = 4 in
let x = x + 1 in
x
```

When called, this function will lazily evaluate the x on 4th line, and then we notice that it tries to evaluate x on the third line, which then tries to evaluate the x again on the third line, creating an infinite loop. How can I fix this without renaming the x in x + 1 on the third line?

Comment: change order? `myfunc = let x = let x = 4 in x + 1 in x`

Comment: Horrible non-recursive-let-desugaring in lambdas follows: `(\x -> (\x -> x) (x+1)) 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. All bindings introduced with `=` in Haskell are recursive. (Other languages do sometimes offer non-recursive binding forms, but not Haskell.)

You could do something like

```
myfunc = do
    x <- Identity 4
    x <- Identity (x+1)
    Identity x
```

...but at that point, just renaming `x` to `x'` or something looks pretty attractive in terms of the amount of required finger-typing.

P.S. Calling this `myfunc` is a bit odd -- it's not a function!

Comment: See rampion's comment. Also, lambda forms introduce non-recursive bindings.